# How to run below powershell script inside terraform local-exec

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I am trying to change the stack of webapp with the help of local-exec provisioner in terraform template.

```
# Create azure Webapp 1
resource "azurerm_app_service" "webapp1" {
  name                = var.webapp1
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.dev.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.dev.name
  app_service_plan_id = azurerm_app_service_plan.dev.id
  https_only          = "true"
  site_config {
    always_on                 = "true"
    ftps_state                = "FtpsOnly"
    dotnet_framework_version  = "v4.0"
    http2_enabled             = "true"
    min_tls_version           = "1.2"
    use_32_bit_worker_process = "false"
    default_documents = ["hostingstart.html"]

  }
 provisioner "local-exec" {
 command =<<EOT  
$PropertiesObject = @{"CURRENT_STACK" = "dotnetcore"}
New-AzResource -PropertyObject $PropertiesObject -ResourceGroupName azurerm_resource_group.dev.name -ResourceType Microsoft.Web/sites/config/metadata -ResourceName azurerm_app_service.webapp1.name -ApiVersion 2018-02-01 -Force
EOT}
```

But it is giving me the below error:

```
azurerm_app_service.webapp1 (local-exec): Executing: ["cmd" "/C" "    $PropertiesObject = @{\r\n    \"CURRENT_STACK\" = \"dotnetcore\"\r\n    }\r\n    New-AzResource -PropertyObject $PropertiesObject -ResourceGroupName azurerm_resource_group.dev.name -ResourceType Microsoft.Web/sites/config/metadata -ResourceName azurerm_app_service.webapp1.name -ApiVersion 2018-02-01 -Force  \r\n"]
azurerm_app_service.webapp1 (local-exec): '$PropertiesObject' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
azurerm_app_service.webapp1 (local-exec): operable program or batch file.


Error: Error running command '    $PropertiesObject = @{
    "CURRENT_STACK" = "dotnetcore"
    }
    New-AzResource -PropertyObject $PropertiesObject -ResourceGroupName azurerm_resource_group.dev.name -ResourceType Microsoft.Web/sites/config/metadata -ResourceName azurerm_app_service.webapp1.name -ApiVersion 2018-02-01 -Force
': exit status 1. Output: '$PropertiesObject' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Any idea how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I rather work with files and not raw script since the script might change in the future and it's more readable and comfortable to change it in a separate file.

Follow bellow steps-

1. Create new file for the PowerShell script( make sure the extension is .ps1)
2. Paste the following code:

```bsh
Param
(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
    [string]$ResourceGroupName,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
    [string]$ResourceType,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
    [string]$ApiVersion,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
    [string]$PropertiesObject
)   

New-AzResource -PropertyObject $PropertiesObject -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -ResourceType $ResourceType -ResourceName $ResourceName -ApiVersion $ApiVersion -Force
```

3. Create relevant variables:

```sh
variable "apiversion" {
    type = "string"
    default = "2018-02-01"
}
variable "resourcetype" {
    type = "string"
    default = "Microsoft.Web/sites/config/metadata 1"
}

variable "propertiesobject" {
  type    = "map"
  default = {
    "CURRENT_STACK" = "dotnetcore"
  }
}
```

4. Excute the script and pass relevant arguments:

```sh
    provisioner "local-exec" {
        command = "PowerShell -file .\%FILE NAME FROM STEP 1%.ps1 -ResourceGroupName azurerm_resource_group.dev.name -ResourceType ${var.resourcetype} -ApiVersion ${var.apiversion} -PropertiesObject ${var.propertiesobject} "
    }
```

This example haven'et been tested but this is how I'm working with other PowerShell scripts.

Comment: Let me give it a try.

Comment: Sure, there might be some issues with passing map variables into the PowerShell script. In worse cases write it hardcoded into the script.
Let me know if I can assist

Comment: @VivekSingh, did you test the solution? is it working?

Comment: @MoonHorse I tested a very similar solution and it's working.. if this example doesn't please let me know and I'll fix it